# Camera moves location when rendered. Why?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, append

The final render is different than the camera view previous to rendering. Not sure where I went wrong.

This is the camera view:
[image]

This what the render spits out:
[image]

Camera and Output settings:

[image] [image]

Through my detective work I've figured out that the butterfly object is the problem. I appended it from a previous file into this one and that's when the render messes up. I've tried starting a completely fresh file and and rendered the basic cube and the camera was perfectly fine. However, once I dropped in the butterfly it gets wacky. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As tod doeh has indicated, there are plenty of potential reasons for this, and you're not showing everything.  Another potential reason is some kind of dependency loop.  People would need a file to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the file, I kind of don't think it is an object (butterfly) problem. My guess is that you have different viewport and camera focal length and/or shift settings (make them the same). Maybe you have lock camera to viewport on. Turn that off (in the right side tabs).

Also maybe instead of appending try opening both blender files in separate 'blenders', and then copy/paste the butterfly object rather than appending. You might be appending some subtle thing that gets pulled in by the append functionality.